# Express (NodeJS) not applying projectors

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

In Mongo, I can run the following that returns a subset of the fields

```
db.IPs.find({},{_id:0,IntegrityID:1,Timestamp:1})
```

However, when I try to do the same in Express, all the fields are returned. It's as if the projector is being ignored.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('IPs');
    collection.find({},{_id:0,IntegrityID:1,Timestamp:1},function(e,docs){
        res.json(docs);
    });
});
```

Comment: What version of the (presumably) MongoDB Native driver are you using?  You can check by using the "npm ls" command.

Comment: I did have ~2.0.33 in my package.json file, which I'd copied from an online tutorial. I thought this may be incompatible so I've remove the line and tried running **npm install mongodb** but I'm now getting an error because I don't have python installed. I'll try installing Python

Comment: I've installed Python but now I'm getting an error about 'Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe"' The .Net 3.5 (inc 2.0) feature is enabled in Windows 10 but I assume that it needs the build tools, so I'm now downloading Visual Studio Express (8GB).

Comment: ├─┬ mongodb@2.0.43
│ ├── es6-promise@2.1.1
│ ├─┬ mongodb-core@1.2.12
│ │ ├── bson@0.4.11
│ │ └─┬ kerberos@0.0.14
│ │   └── nan@2.0.9
│ └─┬ readable-stream@1.0.31
│   ├── core-util-is@1.0.1
│   ├── inherits@2.0.1
│   ├── isarray@0.0.1
│   └── string_decoder@0.10.31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the syntax you are using is based on a different driver than you're using.  Here is an example from the 2.x documentation:

```
  // Peform a simple find and return all the documents
    collection.find({}, {skip:1, limit:1, fields:{b:1}}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
      test.equal(null, err);
      test.equal(1, docs.length);
      test.equal(null, docs[0].a);
      test.equal(2, docs[0].b);
```

Note that the second `find` argument includes more than just the fields to project.  Try tweaking your query to wrap the projection in a `fields` object.

```
collection.find({},{fields:{_id:0,IntegrityID:1,Timestamp:1}},function(e,docs){
    res.json(docs);
});
```

You may also want to consider using `toArray` like the example documentation rather than passing in the callback, but that is just a stylistic suggestion.

Node MongoDB Native 2.0 documentation for `collection.find` is [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#find).

Node MongoDB Native 1.4.9 documentation for `collection.find` is [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/queries.html).

Comment: Thank you. Very simple when you know how!